# How to set even page numbers to left footer, and odd right in REVTeX?

Tags: page-numbering, revtex, footer

I learned that `fancyhdr` package seems to do the job, so I tried

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,notitlepage]{revtex4-1}
......
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
......
```

But it turns out all the page numbers appear in the right footer.

Comment: @campa Thanks very much! Adding a `twoside` option works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mechanism which distinguishes between even/odd pages can work only if the document is set in `twoside` mode, which is supported by the class `revtex4-1`. However, while the result is the one you want, you'll get a warning that it's not working, even if it is. The reason is that `fancyhdr` works best for the standard classes, and `revtex4-1` has a slightly different way of implementing the `twoside` option. As a workaround to suppress the warning you can manually set `\@twosidetrue`.

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,notitlepage,twoside]{revtex4-1}

\makeatletter
\@twosidetrue % workaround to suppress misleading warning
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks also for providing the extra information!